# How do I make Vim go inside paired characters automatically during Insert Mode?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I always type paired characters by pairs:

```
'' "" () [] {} <>
```

How do I map Vim immediately jump inside them when I type them during Insert Mode? I tried some googling but I can't seem to get the right search term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`AutoClose` plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849), which will insert the closing brace for you, leaving your cursor inside them. If you type the matching bracket quickly enough, it will move your cursor outside the pair.

Comment: An alternative to AutoClose is [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) if you find AutoClose isn't everything you wanted.  I don't remember the advantages off hand but I remember there were features in delimitMate that were missing in AutoClose.

Comment: Thanks Randy! delimitMate does exactly what OP wanted (and me too), with the following line in .vimrc: 

`let delimitMate_autoclose = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Without using any plugin, I found out I could use this:

```
inoremap '' ''<esc>i
inoremap "" ""<esc>i
inoremap () ()<esc>i
inoremap [] []<esc>i
inoremap {} {}<esc>i
inoremap <> <><esc>i
```